# PHP: How to reslove This Uncaught Error: Class Not Found

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, uncaught-exception

I tried to send mails using **PHPMailer** through a SMTP account, but I got an error, the error is as follows:

> **Fatal error:**  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\YCS\fun.php:27

**Here is the code:**

*config.php*

```php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    
require 'vendor/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'vendor/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'vendor/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
require 'fun.php';
```

*index.php*

```php
<?php
  require 'config.php';
?>
```

*fun.php*

```php
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);    
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 
    
$mail->IsSMTP();                                         
$mail->Host = $_CONFIG["SenderEmail"]["host"];           
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                  
$mail->Username = $_CONFIG["SenderEmail"]["mail"];       
$mail->Password = $_CONFIG["SenderEmail"]["pass"];        
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                             
$mail->Port = 587;                                      
    
$mail->AddAddress($email, $name);                                 
    
    
$mail->SetFrom($_CONFIG["SenderEmail"]["mail"], $_CONFIG["SenderEmail"]["name"]);
    
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Subject = "Verification Code";
$mail->Body    = "<h1>".$code."</h1>";
    
$mail->Send();
$result = array('response'=>'success');
```

Comment: DId you include something that includes the PHPMailer stuff in the `fun.php` like the `config.php` file

Comment: your index.php isn't being used here. As hinted at already, you need to include that config in your fun.php file, too.

Comment: It basically means that php cannot find the class definition that you are trying to instantiate in fun.php, an include to the file that houses the definition should fix it. keep in mind the path is  correct  (it would be include or include_once)

Comment: do you use composer? then you can use require 'vendor/autoload.php';